# Cypher, ID function in WHERE clausing using c# graph client

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I want to translate something like

```
MATCH (s)
WHERE ID(s) = 65110
RETURN s
```

into C# to use it with the Graph client. My main problem is that I want to get a node by using the internal id of Neo4j, which is absolutely no problem in Cypher but how can I do this in Graph client?

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("(s)")
    .Where((Event s) => ID(s) == 65110)
    .Return(...);
```

This was my first approach but of course that does not work. Can you tell me how to use this ID function of Cypher to get a node with a specific internal Neo4j id by using the Graph client for C#?

For explanation, client is a variable, that connects to the Graph Client of Neo4j:

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "username", "Password");
client.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a parameter here, as that's the best way to ensure the query will be compiled and cached, obviously you could just put in the ID. Generally - you want to avoid using the `ID` of a `Neo4j` item, in fact - I would strongly urge you to add you're own ID field. But! here it is anyhews :)

```
var query = client.Cypher
      .Match("(s)")
      .Where("ID(s) = {idParam}")
      .WithParam("idParam", 65110)
      .Return(s => s.As<Node<string>>());
```